# PHP: AdjacentElementsProduct - CodeFights https://app.codesignal.com/arcade/intro/level-2/

Tags: php

**QUESTION:**

Given an array of integers, find the pair of adjacent elements that has the largest product and return that product.

**Example:**

https://app.codesignal.com/arcade/intro/level-2

For inputArray = [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3], the output should be
adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) = 21.

7 and 3 produce the largest product.

**Input/Output**

Input:
inputArray: [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]

Expected Output:
21

**SOLUTION: My code that doesn't work:**

```
function adjacentElementsProduct($inputArray) {
    $total = 0;
    $temp = 0;
    $maxProduct = 0;
    $var = 0;

    if ($inputArray.count == 1) return 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $inputArray[$inputArray.count-1]; $i++) {
        if ($inputArray[i] + $inputArray[i+1] > $maxProduct) {
            $maxProduct = $inputArray[i] * $inputArray[i+1];    
        }
    }

    return $maxProduct;
}
```

Comment: This link not working, and these snippets are for HTML/CSS/JS only

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to ask a question in PHP? this code snippet is not valid PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with any programming task, the trick is to tackle it piece by piece. You tend to find your code is more readable when you break problems down into small components.

You need to:

- Find the product of adjacent elements in an array
- Find the largest product in that group of values

You can approach this without a large number of variables, nesting, etc.

```
function adjacentElementsProduct(array $inputs) {
    $products = [];

    for ($i = 1; $i < count($inputs); $i++) {
        $products[] = $inputs[$i - 1] * $inputs[$i];
    }

    return max($products);
}
```

All we're doing is looping through the input array, starting with the second element. Calculating the product of the previous element and the current element then putting the result into an array of products. Finally we run that through `max()` which is going to handle finding the largest value for us.

Important to note: there's no validation taking place here. Can you trust that your array will only ever contain numerical values? Will it always contain at least two elements? If not you'll want to account for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it

```
$inputArray =  [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3];

function adjacentElementsProduct($inputArray) {
   $max = 0;
   for($i = 0; $i < (sizeof($inputArray) - 1); $i++){
       $b = $i+1;
       if($inputArray[$i] > 0 && $inputArray[$b] > 0){
           $max = (($inputArray[$i] * $inputArray[$b]) > $max) ? ($inputArray[$i] * $inputArray[$b]) : $max;
       }
   }

   return $max;
}

echo adjacentElementsProduct($inputArray); // Outputs 21
```

Comment: Correct except it can be negative numbers so >0 is unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

```
function adjacentElementsProduct($inputArray) {
    $res = [];
    
    for($j=0;$j<count($inputArray);$j++){
        $res[] = $inputArray[$j]*$inputArray[$j+1];
    }
    return (max($res) < 0) ? 0 : max($res);
}
```

Comment: Hi Rahul. Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.

Answer (score -1):

As with any programming task, the trick is to tackle it piece by piece. You tend to find your code is more readable when you break problems down into small components.

You need to:

Find the product of adjacent elements in an array
Find the largest product in that group of values
In PHP its as below:

```
function adjacentElementsProduct($inputArray) {
        $res = [];
        
        for($j=1;$j<count($inputArray);$j++){
            $res[] = $inputArray[$j-1]*$inputArray[$j];
        }
        return max($res);
    }
    
    $a = [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]
    echo adjacentElementsProduct($a); //21
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.